# iPad not reading my plists

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad, plist

When I add an plists-file to my XCode project, my iPad app can't seem to read it.

For example: I have massCategories.plist inside my project's folder (where the xproj-file lives). Inside my plist is the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Item 1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key 1</key>
        <string>Value 1</string>
        <key>Key 2</key>
        <string>Value 2</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Item 2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key 3</key>
        <string>Value 3</string>
        <key>Key 4</key>
        <string>Value 4</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Inside my ViewController I have the following method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *plistData = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"MassCategories" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *massCategories = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistData];
    // breakpoint
}
```

When running (and "pausing" at the breakpoint), massCategories contains nil.
Adding the plist file to another folder doesn't seem to work (or I must be using the wrong folders, which is well possible :-)).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Just update the plist such that the main element is an array (just as I should've expected when trying to import it as an array):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
...
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you get your naming right aswell. You say the file is called 'massCategories.plist' but you try to load @"MassCategories". iOS is case sensitive.

Comment: Just click twice on the file's name.

Comment: I meant that I hadn't found a way to change only the case: when changing the case, XCode complains that the file already exists..